# Access Mac from iPad graphically without installations on the Mac

Tags: macos, ipad

In OS X Lion there is the possibility of screen sharing. I wonder how to access my Mac from my iPad without installing anything on the Mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try enabling Screen Sharing (in the "Sharing" preference pane of the System Preferences app) on your Mac. This will start a VNC server on your local machine. You could then install a VNC Client on your iPad (Mocha Lite is a free one) and view/interact with your applications.

Comment: excellent now it works, i did not realize that it would be  a default VNC server from lion